# Java retrieve returned ArrayList to HashMap

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my simple java application i have this function to return `ArrayList`:

`Items.java` class:

```
package com.example.Hadis;

/**
 * Created by tux-world on 8/1/14.
 */
public class Items {

    public int id;
    public String content;
}
```

ArrayList function for fill and return result:

`DataBaseHelper.java` class's  `getFavorite` function :

```
public ArrayList<Items> getFavorite(){
    ArrayList<Items> arrayList = new ArrayList<Items>();

    do {

        Items dbItems = new Items();

        dbItems.id = cursor.getInt(0);
        dbItems.content = cursor.getString(1);
        arrayList.add(dbItems);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    return arrayList;
}
```

i want to fetch this return `ArrayList` and fill HashMap but i can not program this part of project

Defined map as Method in class:

```
    static Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

retrive `ArrayList` and my problem is this:

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ApplicationHadith.this);
    ArrayList<Items> list = db.getFavorite();

    Iterator<Items> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {

      // map.put( it.id , it.content )

    }
```

how to retrive `getFavorite()` and fill `HashMap`? please help me.Thanks

Comment: What *specifically* is your problem ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew retrive `getFavorite()` and fill `HashMap` map

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions just because you don't get the answer you want in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a simple for loop e.g.

```
for (Item item : list) {
   map.put( item.id, item.content);
}
```

I wouldn't normally use an `Iterator` in this scenario. The [enhanced for-loop syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) above dates from Java 5.

Comment: Wow you just barely beat me to it! I'll remove mine since it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the iterator's `next()` method to get the instance of `Items` :

```
Iterator<Items> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
  Items item = it.next();
  map.put( item.getID() , item );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(it.hasNext())
    {
Item item = (Item) it.next();

       map.put( item.getId() , item.getContent() )

    }
```

Have getters generated for id and content